# Socket timeout Tomcat7

Tags: sockets, load, timeout, tomcat7

I am trying to run a LoadUI Load test on Tomcat 7 fronted by Apache 2.2 on win 2003 server on ec2. I keep getting socket timeout errors when I try to increase the users in the Load test.It fails currently when running 20 users synchronously. The server becomes totally unresponsive.

```
-Xmx1024m,-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

I have used in tomcat's server.xml the following:

```
maxThreads="250",connectionTimeout="20000
```

The server shows 100% CPU usage but not full heap usage.

My next step is to try with

```
maxThreads="250",connectionTimeout="60000",acceptCount="250",maxkeepAliverequest="1"
```

I have set on Apache httpd.conf:

```
keepAlive on, ThreadsPerChild 250, MaxRequestsPerChild 0
```

Answer (score 0):

jvisualvm.exe from the jdk1.6 and heapdumps from the GUI were a huge help.The dominator tree under the heapdump and the largest objects under it ultimately pointed me to the memory leak.I also used Eclipse MAT to look at the heapdumps effectively.

I also reduced maxThreads to 200 to reduce CPU consumption and increased the acceptCount queue to 500.